# Silverstripe 3.1 Spam Protection

Tags: captcha, spam, silverstripe, spam-prevention

I can't get any of the spam protection modules to show a captcha / maths test etc for page comments.

I have a default install of the comments module, spamprotection module & iv'e tried the mollum, recaptcha and maths spam protectors

I'm setting the site config like this:

```
SpamProtectorManager::set_spam_protector('MollomSpamProtector');
```

and setting the various api keys, visiting: dev/build/flush=all and testing in a different browser so i'm not logged in as admin. Iv'e cleared the cache and have the site in dev mode.

At no point has any spam protection shown up. I know it doesn't by default with Mollum so i tried to trigger it with some nice spammy looking content but I can't trigger the captcha. The Molluum report doesn't get listed in the admin/reports area either.

What am I doing wrong here? I must be missing something in setting up the base spamprotection module right? Or the Comments module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to simon welsh on irc, I found the answer.

in your _config.php file, do this:

```
CommentingController::add_extension('CommentSpamProtection');
```

and the spam protection is enabled for comments.